# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value Python, mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysqlconnector

Есть программа которая должна добавлять данные из tsv в базу данных MySql, и когда я хочу загрузить очередной файл, получаю ошибку

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'parent_order_id' at row 1

Суть в том что столбец почти полностью пустой и там только иногда бывают данные типа int, как вы понимаете parent_order_id типа int)

Снизу привожу код которым делаю такую загрузку и фрагмент таблицы

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

config = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': 'root',
  'host': 'localhost',
  'unix_socket': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
  'database': 'marketing',
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}
database = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = database.cursor(dictionary=True)

with open('sandbox.KNU/marketing/orders.tsv') as tsvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        values = \[row\["order_id"\], row\["dt"\], row\["user_id"\], row\["gross"\], row\["type_id"\], row\["context_id"\], row\["parent_order_id"\]\]
        print(values)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO orders (order_id, dt, user_id, gross, type_id, context_id, parent_order_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", values)

database.commit()
cursor.close()][1]][1]
```

Comment: ну а какой тип имеет parent_order_id? и какой тип имеет поле в базе для этой переменной? разрешены ли в нем пустые значения (NUL)?

Comment: попробовал поменять тип в базе данных на varchar и все заработало, но пустые значения хочу сделать null, как я могу этого добится?

Comment: row["parent_order_id"] or None